# How can I exclude a selected directory using regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, xml, cordova-plugins

I want to exclude only plugins folder on encryption files for my production

```
D:\AppName\platforms\app\plugins\main\assets\www\plugins\different-foldernames\www\differentfilenames.js

D:\AppName\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\js\build\differentfilenames.js
D:\AppName\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\differentfilenames.js
D:\AppName\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\css\build\differentfilenames.css
```

my regex in plugin.xml

```xml
<include>
      <file regex="\.(htm|html|js|css)$"/>
</include>
<exclude>
      <file regex="/plugins/(.*).js$" />
</exclude>
```

seems like my regex is not working

Comment: Look, you have ``\`` as directory separator, but you use  `/` in the pattern. Try `<file regex="[\\/]plugins[\\/].*\.js$" />`

Comment: its still encrypting man

Comment: I edit my question, I added the assets/www that should only be included

Comment: The base [`plugin.xml` format](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html) does not have `<include>` or `<exclude>` elements. Is this a configuration for some specific plugin, and if so, which one?

Comment: yes this is a configuration of a specific plugin, check cordova-plugin-crypto-file